# C++ array passed into function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an object named thingy with a method playWithString(char* text).
I have a character array such as
    char *testString = nullptr;
I want to pass testString into thingy.playWithString(char* text)

I initially tried this by putting this at the start of the playWithString method
    text = new char[128]
This works fine in the function, but once the function has ended testString is null again. How do I make it retain the value of the function result?

Comment: Could you please provide your actual code? ... But if you want to change your char-pointer within the `playWithString` method you have to change its parameter to a reference-to-pointer or pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: `char testString = nullptr;` isn't an array. Please clarify your question, adding some realistic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass by reference here. This is what is happening:

```
void playWithString (char* myptr) {
    myPtr = new char [128];
    //myPtr is a local variable and will not change the fact that testString still points to NULL
    *myPtr = 'a';
    *myPtr = 'b';
}

main () {
    char *testString = NULL; //testString is not pointing to anything
    playWithString(testString);
    //tesString is still null here

}
```

To solve this: Pass by reference. Notice the & in signature of playWithString.

```
void playWithString (char* &myptr) {
    myPtr = new char [128];
    //myPtr is a local variable and will not change the fact that testString still points to NULL
    *myPtr = 'a';
    *myPtr = 'b';
}

main () {
    char *testString = NULL; //testString is not pointing to anything
    playWithString(testString);
    //tesString is still null here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to modify the pointer, not the data to which the pointer is pointing. When you create a function, the parameters are ordinarily passed by value unless you make the parameter a pointer or a reference. This means that the parameters are copied and thus assignment to the parameter only modifies a copy, not the original object. In the case where the parameter is a pointer (array parameters are represented as a pointer to the first element in the array), the pointer is being copied (although the content to which it points is the same both outside and inside the function). With this pointer, you can modify the content to which it points and have the effect persist outside of the function; however, modifying the pointer itself (e.g. to make it point to a different array) is only modifying the copy; if you want such a mutation to last outside the function, you need an extra layer of indirection. In other words, you need to pass a pointer or reference to the pointer to be able to change its target.

P.S. As others have noted, for using strings, you really should use an `std::string`. That being said, it's good to understand the underlying mechanics and how to use `char*` when learning.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use c++ strings (std::string) ?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    void foo(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    A a;

    std::string str = "Hello!";
    a.foo(str);

    return 0;
}
```